# What is the behavior when a printf specifier flag is repeated?

Tags: c, printf, language-lawyer

`fprintf()` family of functions have 5 *flag* characters `'-'`, `'+'`, `' '`, `'#'`, `'0'`.

What is the specified behavior, if any, when a flag is *repeated*?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  printf("%  d\n", 12);     //  12
  printf("%00d\n", 34);     // 34
  printf("%++d\n", 56);     // +56
  printf("%00*d\n", 5, 78); // 00078
  return 0;
}
```

With my gcc "i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.2" I receive "warning: repeated ' ' flag in format [-Wformat=]", so I assume this is a correct behavior--> warn user and allow repeated flag.

I have yet to find a C99/C11 specification guidance for this corner issue found while trying to write a format parser.

If repeating allowed, the following code is OK.  If repeating is not allowed, the 2nd `0` is the width.  Then the specifier has 2 widths `0` and `*`, which is another problem.

```
// -------v
printf("%00*d\n", 5, 78); // 00078
```

Comment: FWIW, I get the same results on VS 2008 and VS 2010.

Comment: Certainly no warning is required, even for an incorrect format string. Format strings can be constructed at run time; in the general case, the compiler can't tell whether it's correct. Some compilers, such as gcc, warning about an incorrect format string when it's a literal (the most common case). (This doesn't answer your question about whether repeated flags are allowed.)

Comment: I have seen a few implementations of `printf` and I have written at least 4 different ones. They all handle repeated flags as equivalent to a single flag, for the very simple reason that it is much simpler to do so and for the few implementers that wonder about it, it does not seem to be incorrect.

Comment: @chqrlie Agree that it is  simpler to handle repeated flags as equivalent to a single flag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion, the standard is unclear on this point.

The authors of gcc were clearly of the opinion that repeated flags are invalid, since gcc issues a warning by default for something like:

```
printf("%++d\n", 42);
```

but that doesn't necessarily tell us what the authors of the standard intended.

The standard permits:

> Zero or more *flags* (in any order) that modify the meaning of the conversion
>   specification.

The flags are `-`, `+`, *space*, `#`, and `0`. The phrase "Zero or more flags* is, I think, specifically intended to permit *different* flags to be combined.  For example, this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("|%6x|\n", 0x123);
    printf("|%-6x|\n", 0x123);
    printf("|%#6x|\n", 0x123);
    printf("|%-#6x|\n", 0x123);
    printf("|%#-6x|\n", 0x123);
}
```

is valid and produces this output:

```
|   123|
|123   |
| 0x123|
|0x123 |
|0x123 |
```

In other contexts, the standard is explicit about whether a construct may or may not be repeated. For example, `long long int` is distinct from `long int`, and `long int int` is a syntax error.  On the other hand, the standard explicitly says (N1570 6.7.3p5) that:

> If the same qualifier appears more than once in the same
>   *specifier-qualifier-list*, either directly or via one or more
>   **`typedefs`**, the behavior is the same as if it appeared only once.

The lack of any such statement here makes me suspect that the authors of the standard didn't consider the case of repeating the same flag.

If I'm incorrect about this, and the committee did intend a repeated flag to be equivalent to a single flag, then your format parser should treat them as equivalent. If I'm correct, then the behavior of repeating the same flag is undefined, and your implementation can do anything you like -- including treating them as equivalent to a single flag.

In either case, you're free to issue a warning if you like. Even if the standard defines the behavior of a repeated flag, it's still arguably poor style and worth warning about.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour `printf("%d", 10.1);` also doesn't cause gcc to issue anything beyond a warning, even with `-pedantic-errors`.

Comment: @T.C.: As far as the standard is concerned, `printf("%d", 10.1)` simply has undefined behavior. An implementation may diagnose it, or even reject it, but it's not *required* to do anything in particular. If it's in a context like `if (0) printf("%d", 10.0);` it *shouldn't* be rejected.

Comment: I know that. My comment was in response to Shafik's (since deleted) comment that gcc's not upgrading the repeated-flags warning to an error with `-pedantic-errors` indicates that it thinks it's conforming.

Comment: @T.C. Indeed, my original thought was that warning produced by Wformat are not all due to invalid programs but I realized that you need Werror to them into errors regardless.

Answer (score 2):

In the C standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function) there is written only that

> 4 Each conversion specification is introduced by the character %.
>   After the %, the following appear in sequence:
>
> — **Zero or more flags (in any order)** that modify the meaning of the
>   conversion specification.

So I suppose that flags may be repeated. Otherwise there would be some restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

The standard says:

> 7.19.6.1/4 Zero or more flags (in any order) that modify the meaning of the conversion specification.

"zero or more flags" is obviously intended to allow for more than one flag to be specified. It makes sense that if a flag is repeated,  it has the same meaning as the flag appearing only once.